How can I load an image to an ImageView without reducing its original size, while scaling it down to the dimensions on the ImageView?
I can load drawable into an ImageView, and save it afterwards. But the saved image is smaller in size than the original one. I suspect it is the size of the ImageView. How can I load an image into an ImageView while keeping its original size. I am not referring to scale.
I checked all the scaling parameters of the ImageView, hoping to find one that does not actually scale the actual image, but just the view of the image, none of the options seem to achieve that I need.

If you already have a drawable to load into the ImageView, why would you save it from the ImageView?  Save the original.
